# Code capture automated

Tags: python, video, automation

I am doing a project, where we need a video of the python script being written in the editor. We have 100+ scripts, so we need automation. Is there a program, in which the input is your python script and output is a video that writes that code charactet by character in an editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I must say that this "requirement" sounds quite weird, nothing is impossible. You can achieve this with a small script, as I'm going to show below.

---

#### Preparation

First of all, we need to install some tools. These are `xdotool` for the typing emulation and window control, and `byzanz` for the video recording. Install them using:

```
sudo apt install xdotool byzanz
```

Next, copy the code at the end of this answer and save it as bash script on your machine, e.g. as `~/bin/typerec`. If you store it in a folder on your `$PATH`, you'll be able to execute it without specifying its path. Don't forget to make it executable afterwards using `chmod +x PATH/TO/SCRIPT`.

---

#### Usage

Now to record the typing of a specific file, first open your target editor, into which we shall type. Make sure that it has any kind of "auto indentation" feature turned off, otherwise the indentation of the typed code will be messed!

Then launch my script e.g. from a terminal. The correct syntax is

```
typerec INPUT_FILE OUTPUT_FILE [DELAY]
```

where `INPUT_FILE` is the path to your code text file and `OUTPUT_FILE` is the output file path where the recording shall be stored. It must have an extension accepted by `byzanz`, i.e. one of **`gif`**, **`webm`**, **`ogg`**, `ogv`, `flv`, `byzanz` (my recommendations in bold). The `DELAY` argument is optional and sets the delay between two keystrokes in milliseconds. Default is 20 if omitted, I recommend not going below 5.

Example:

```
typerec /path/to/my/code.py ~/Videos/code.webm 100
```

Your mouse cursor will change to some kind of cross-hair (not visible in the screenshot) and you will get a notification bubble asking you to click the target editor window now:

[image: typerec "select target window" notification]

Do as you're told, but **be careful**! If you did not want to start the recording, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> immediately, while the terminal is still focused and before clicking anywhere.

> **Warning!**
>   As soon as you click anywhere, the script will focus that window and start emulating all the keystrokes to type your input document a second later. **This is not stoppable!** Once it started, **do not touch your keyboard or click anywhere until it finished!**  Otherwise your input will mix with the emulated input and may trigger unintended actions, like opening/focusing other windows or activating keyboard shortcuts. You must wait until it stops on its own!

That's it. Once the script finished (note that after the recording is done, it might still need a few more seconds to render and save the video), you can open the recorded video and check the results.

[image: Example output (input <code>~/.profile</code>, output <code>typerec.gif</code>, default delay of <code>20</code> ms)]

---

#### Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
THIS="$(basename "$0")"
INPUT_FILE="$1"
OUTPUT_FILE="$2"
DELAY="${3:-20}"

show_usage() {
    echo "  Usage:  $THIS INPUT_FILE OUTPUT_FILE [DELAY]"
    echo "where INPUT_FILE is the text file with the content to be typed"
    echo "and OUTPUT_FILE is where the recorded video shall get saved."
    echo "You can set the DELAY between keystrokes in ms (default 20)."
    echo "Note that OUTPUT_FILE will be overwritten if it exists already."
    echo "It must have one of the extensions {gif|webm|ogg|ogv|flv|byzanz}."
    exit 1
}

if [[ -z "$INPUT_FILE" || ! -r "$INPUT_FILE" ]] ; then
    echo "Missing INPUT_FILE argument or file is not existing or readable!"
    show_usage
fi
if [[ -z "$OUTPUT_FILE" ]] ; then
    echo "Missing OUTPUT_FILE argument!"
    show_usage
fi
if [[ ! "$DELAY" -gt 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Invalid argument for DELAY, must be a number > 0 or omitted."
    show_usage
fi

notify-send -i "media-record" "$THIS" "Please select your target editor window."
eval $(xdotool selectwindow getwindowgeometry --shell)
if [[ -z "$WINDOW" || -z "$X" || -z "$Y" || -z "$WIDTH" || -z "$HEIGHT" ]]; then
    echo "Failed to obtain all required target window information. Aborting."
    exit 2
fi

TYPE_COMMAND="xdotool windowactivate --sync \"$WINDOW\" \
              getactivewindow \
              windowfocus --sync \
              sleep 1 \
              type --clearmodifiers --delay "$DELAY" \
                   --file <( tr \\\\n \\\\r < \"$INPUT_FILE\" )"

byzanz-record -e "bash -c '$TYPE_COMMAND'" \
        -x "$X" -y "$Y" -w "$WIDTH" -h "$HEIGHT" \
        "$OUTPUT_FILE" &&

echo "Recording screencast and saving to $OUTPUT_FILE finished successfully."
```

---

#### Alternative one-liner

If you prefer not to save the script anywhere, a one-liner which you can simply paste into the terminal that basically does the same (but omitting input parameters and validations, recording `file.txt` as `typerec.gif` with a delay of 20 ms) is below. You're responsible for editing it to use the correct paths and making sure everything is correct yourself there.

```
( eval $(xdotool selectwindow getwindowgeometry --shell) ; byzanz-record -e "bash -c 'xdotool windowactivate --sync $WINDOW getactivewindow windowfocus --sync sleep 1 type --clearmodifiers --delay 20 --file <( tr \\\\n \\\\r < file.txt )'" -x $X -y $Y -w $WIDTH -h $HEIGHT typerec.gif )
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, it works like a charm, thank so much : )

Comment: @dibil08 Nice. If it solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the grey round check button on its left. Thank you.